# What do I need to do to make Datadog show 500's as errors?

Tags: devops, datadog

I inherited a Datadog instance, and I'm not familiar with how the errors are set up.  I have a JavaScript application that is successfully reporting its Status codes, and giving me a lot of useful metrics.  However, we are regularly seeing `500` status codes.  In the metadata for the event, they are showing as errors, and the status code is red.  However, as you can see in the image below, my status shows 0 Errors, and our chart shows no errors.

On the left, 0 errors, even though there are 500's.  This image is the APM->Services.  The actual Error Tracking page does show errors, but not the 500's.

[image]

The graph above reflects the same output.  It's showing no errors, as if the 500's don't exist, or as if the 500's aren't marked as errors.

I've been reading about their [Error Tracking](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/error_tracking/), but I haven't had any luck finding exactly how to tell Datadog that the 500's are errors.  Especially since it seems like it's already aware that they are errors.

I'm still reading through the docs and [getting started section](https://docs.datadoghq.com/getting_started/), but I'm kind of pressed for time on figuring out how to set up the errors. TIA

Comment: is that a screenshot from Logs or from Error Tracking? Since you don't know how things have been configured in the past, check to see if your response codes have been mapped to the correct status codes in the Log Status Remapper; there are docs for remapping them https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/guide/remap-custom-severity-to-official-log-status/

Comment: @bwest The screenshot is from APM->Services.  I'll add it to the original question, but in Error Tracking it does show some errors, but none of the 500's.  I'll look into the documentation you linked, thanks.